# Parallel Approvers an field update

Tags: approval-process, field-update, configuration

I am creating an approval process and it is submitted to 2 users for approval(ex. Legal and finance). When one of the user(Ex. Legal) approves the record, I want to update a field(Picklist - Legal approval status) on the record based on which user has approved.

After that when other user approves the record, I want to update other field(Picklist - financeapproval status). The record is submitted in only one step. Can anyone help how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: is that 2 approvals will be one by one, that first Legal will approve then automatically it will submitted for approval for Finance to approve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create **2 approval processes**, not the 2 step approval.

Let's say in the process names will be `Legal Approval process` and `Finance Approval Process`.

1. Legal Approval process, final approval action, do a workflow field update which will update picklist `Legal approval status`.

When you configure workflow field update be sure to select **"Re-evaluate Workflow rules after field change"** (***otherwise Process builder's process will not fire***).

2. Create a Process Builder's process which will fire when `Legal approval status` is approved.

And, it will submit for approval of `"Finance Approval Process"`.

3. In the Finance Approval Process, create a workflow field update to `Picklist - financeapproval` status as final approval action.

That's it!

Comment: I am not sure how to do it? Or I don't have enough points to do so.